# Android 'Super expression must either be null or a function' in react-native-gifted-chat

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

When upgrading to the latest version of RN 0.62.0 importing the package leads to `Type Errror: Super expression must either be null or a function`

Comment: Same problem with RN  "^0.62.2"
Tell me if you have a solution for this. thx.

Comment: @amin89  try to replace library version like "react-native-gifted-chat": "https://github.com/StagasaurusRex/react-native-gifted-chat.git#upgrade-action-sheet",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to upgrade `action-sheet` version in `react-native-gifted-chat` in pack

Like

```
"react-native-gifted-chat": "https://github.com/StagasaurusRex/react-native-gifted-chat.git#upgrade-action-sheet",
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this : 
"yarn add https://github.com/StagasaurusRex/react-native-gifted-chat.git#upgrade-action-sheet"
it works!